# Nacl And Pnacl from terminal on chrome device

Tags: chromium, google-nativeclient, chromium-os

I've built `hello world` program by `nacl` and `pnacl` tools from NACL_SDK.
And now I want to test it.
I've mad a html page and js script which are working with my `nexe` and `pexe` and in browser everything is working fine.

But how can I launch my programs from `console`?
And how can I write `stdout` to file?

Answer (score 1):

To run a nexe-program my-app.nexe from console and redirect output to file output.log use the following command:

```
$NACL_SDK/tools/sel_ldr.py my-app.nexe > output.log
```

`sel_ldr.py` is just a helper script. If you pass a `--verbose` option to it, you'll see a real command used to run your program. It's something like this:

```
$NACL_SDK/tools/nacl_helper_bootstrap_x86_64 $NACL_SDK/tools/sel_ldr_x86_64 \
    --r_debug=0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX --reserved_at_zero=0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX -a   \
    -B $NACL_SDK/tools/irt_core_x86_64.nexe my-app.nexe
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but i don't get what's the different between sel_ldr and real device?
And how to run test on real device (e,g.) chrome book.

Comment: I'm not aware of chrome books, but on ARM it can be run the same way using arm-helpers. Unfortunately, there's no respective helpers in NACL_SDK, so you have to build them from sources, I guess.

Comment: But what the difference between realdevice execution and sel_ldr?

Comment: You know that nexe-programs run in a sandbox for the sake of security. `sel_ldr` (secure elf loader) is a heart of this sandbox. It places nexe-module and irt_core, which implements PPAPI, at specific addresses in memory. Internally browser runs your module in a similar way.